# Android : Stack overflow error - Recursive too deeply

Tags: android, recursion, callstack, stack-overflow

I am creating a little game where you need to move troops on a map. To detect if a movement can be done I must verify if there is a way between 2 squares.
So, recursively I start from one square and take the four squares (above, below, left and right) and following conditions I repeat the test recursively since I get only dead-ends or the destination square. All the squares must be under the control of the player.

There is my recursive code implement in my class Case :

```
public boolean isContiguJoueur(Case case_origine, Case case_destination, Case[] cases)  {
 boolean haut_true=false, droite_true=false, bas_true=false, gauche_true=false;
 // Above
 if(this.haut!=null)    {
  if(haut.joueur==this.joueur && this.haut!=case_origine)   {
   if(this.haut==case_destination)  {
    return true;
   }
   haut_true=haut.isContiguJoueur(this,case_destination, cases);
  }
 }
 // ...
 // Same code than Above, only variables names change
 // ...
 return haut_true||droite_true||bas_true||gauche_true;
}
```

- The class name for a square : Case
- The map data : Case[] cases
- The player id : joueur
- The case above : haut

That code work very well on little map (~ 50 to 100 squares). But i got this on bigger ones :

```
08-25 11:26:31.912: E/AndroidRuntime(5497): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 11:26:31.912: E/AndroidRuntime(5497): java.lang.StackOverflowError
08-25 11:26:31.912: E/AndroidRuntime(5497):     at mypackage.isContiguJoueur(Case.java:xxx)
... x 100
```

Sorry for my bad english and thanks for future help ! :-)

**Edit** : I forgot. To avoid mass useless recursive tests I already did this :

```
if(this.droite!=null && !haut_true) {
// ...
if(this.bas!=null && !haut_true && !droite_true)    {
// ...
if(this.gauche!=null && !haut_true && !droite_true && !bas_true)    {
// ...
```

Comment: @Jonathan Actually, I think [stack-overflow] would be the correct tag here.

Comment: @AndrewBarber, thanks, added both. I'm editing a whole load of posts mis-tagged as [tag:overflow] and thought as this is java-specific I'd use the java exception type, but on reflection I agree the more general tag is at least as relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your paths are exponential with the number of squares on the board. The stack overflow error implies you are recursing too many times: each recursion takes up stack space, and you are running out of it (Chaque recursion utilise l'espace sur le pile, et il y'en a trop, alors il n y a plus d'espace - et c'est une dépassement de pile).

You could do this iteratively, (sans recursion) and not run into this problem. But bear in mind the number of possible paths still remains *very* large, and this can be CPU consuming.

Hope This Helps,

TG

Comment: Edit: as for your added tests for useless recursion - still not enough. These tests can be at the end of a path, by which time the stack has already "exploded". Again, iterating, rather than recursing, can work.

Comment: So there is no other way than iteratively ?

Comment: There is always the option of trying a different recursive algorithm, and/or further constrain the recursion. But I can't suggest an algorithm if I don't have more details. Increasing the stack depth will be an interim solution, but will still explode very quickly.

Comment: The problem is my application use too much CPU that i want already. So I don't need a enormously calculus iterative method.
I think I got an idea. I'm gonna work on it tomorrow and post it here.
My problem is simple : how test if there is a way to one square to another? Even if the map is 300*300 squares.
However thanks for the help ! :-)

Comment: Je vous en prie  :-) Au revoir demain matin ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I just add a boolean in my class Case and if I test this Case I set the boolean to true I don't come in later. The improvement is very important !
Before it was about n^4 (n is the number of case owned by the player) tests. Now it is about n. With my biggest map and the player owns the entire map I have no error.